# how to extract multiple patterns from a line with grep/sed/awk and merge them in output

Tags: shell, sed, awk, grep

I have a line of the form

```
bla bla bla RequestId=ABCD1234EFGH bla bla bla bla ResponseId=IJKL5678MNOP bla bla bla
```

I need to get both the RequestId and the ResponseId from this line and output them with a seperator. For example, for this particular line it will be

`ABCD1234EFGH|IJKL5678MNOP`

I can extract one of the values with `grep -oe "RequestId=[0-9|a-z|A-Z|-]*"` but how can i get both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
awk '{
    if (!match($0, /RequestId=([-0-9a-zA-Z]*)/)) next;
    req = (substr($0, RSTART + 10, RLENGTH - 10));
    if (!match($0, /ResponseId=([-0-9a-zA-Z]*)/)) next;
    res = (substr($0, RSTART + 11, RLENGTH - 11));
    printf("%s|%s\n", req, res);
}' yourFile.txt
```

?

Comment: yup this works!! thanks a lot. also why are you printing that way? all i did was `print req "|" res`

Comment: I tend to use `printf` over `print` as a matter of habit, though in this case it doesn't really matter. For fancier formatting, `printf` definitely wins.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if($i ~ /^Req/) { 
        printf $i"|||"
    }
    else {
        if($i ~ /^Res/) {
            print $i 
            }
        }
    }  
}' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
$ perl -nE '$,="|"; say /(?:Request|Response)Id=([-0-9a-zA-Z]*)/g' file
ABCD1234EFGH|IJKL5678MNOP
```